# How to calculate this sum: $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

Where $\lambda$ is a constant.

I reached a sum of this kind when I was trying to solve a task from a  former test on basic probability. Sadly, I've already forgotten enough material from discrete mathematics to be able to solve such a sum or even know if sums of this kind are easily solvable... (If they're not then I definitely should try to approach this task from a different angle)

Comment: This is the Taylor expansion for $e^{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment, The Taylor expansion for the function $e^x$ is given by $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^k}{k!}$$

Some authors use this as the definition of $e^x$.  Alternatively, you can remark that the derivative of the power series is equal to the original series (taking care to verify absolute convergence for all $x$).

We see, of course, that your expression is then $\boxed {e^{\lambda}}$.